# netcat daemon for calling functions in sh script

Tags: shell, sockets, tcp, netcat

I'm new to shell programming and I have created a script that opens a connection to a server of mine. I want to have this script listen for an input from a client node and use that to run a function.

This is my process.
Run script > opens listener > on second computer use netcat to connect > run a function in the script on the server called nodefunction

I have server_port coded to '4444'

File name: run_hangman

```
nc -l -k -v -p 4444 | bash hangman
```

File name: hangman

```
#!/bin/bash

msg_timeout=0
host_ows=1
server_port=4444
dubOws=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

initServer() {
    hostIP=`ip -o addr show dev "eth0" | awk '$3 == "inet" {print $4}' | sed -r 's!/.*!!; s!.*\.!!'`
    hostOws=`echo $hostIP | cut -d . -f 4`
} 
servermsg(){ #message    //if = --n, echos on same line
    if [ "$1" != "--n" ]
    then
        echo `date +"%T"` "[SERVER] "$1
    else
        echo -n `date +"%T"` "[SERVER] "
    fi
}
owsmsg(){    #message    //if = --n, echos on same line
    if [ "$1" != "--n" ]
    then
        echo `date +"%T"` "[OWS]    "$1
    else
        echo -n `date +"%T"` "[OWS]    "
    fi
}
playermsg() {
    if [ "$1" != "--n" ]
    then
        echo `date +"%T"` "[PLAYER]    "$1
    else
        echo -n `date +"%T"` "[PLAYER]    "
    fi
}
question(){  #question, read, example
    servermsg "$1"
    if [ -n "$3" ]
    then
        servermsg "$3"
    fi
    read $2
    echo ""
}
owsArray(){   #
    for targetOws in $player_list
    do
        owsArray+=("OWS"$targetOws)
    done
    echo -n ${owsArray[*]}
    echo
}
openSocket() {
    servermsg "Starting the Game Listener"
    servermsg "Opening Listener on port "$server_port
    #nc -k -l $server_port |bash    
    #nc -kl -q 1 -p $server_port # This should create the listener & This is where everything stops.
    servermsg "Now listening on port "$server_port
}

initServer
owsmsg "Starting server on OWS"$hostOws"..."

question "Enter all the OWSs that will play:" player_list "Example: 1 9 14 23"
echo $player_list
question "Type a category hint:" game_cat "Example: Type of Animal"
question "Type your word:" game_word "Example: zebra"
question "How many guesses:" game_guesses "Example: 7"

servermsg "OWS"$host_ows "has created a Hangman session"
servermsg "Players are:"; servermsg --n; owsArray
servermsg "Your word is "${#game_word}" letters long and players have "$game_guesses" guesses"
question "If this is all correct press enter, or CTRL+C to cancel"

openSocket

# I think I need a While script here to read the RAW input and run the playermsg function with the input?
```

I run the run_hangman file and then I connect to it via my node computer. I enter the following line and echo "1 2 3" because that is what I need. I also can't enter "1 2 3" directly into the window running "run_hangman" as if I press enter it goes to a new line.

```
echo "1 2 3" >/dev/tcp/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/4444
```

The server shows that it connected

```
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 4444)
14:52:24 [OWS]    Starting server on OWS225...
14:52:24 [SERVER] Enter all the OWSs that will play:
14:52:24 [SERVER] Example: 1 9 14 23
Connection from [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 4444 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 41564)
Connection closed, listening again.

1 2 3
```

Now once it gets to openSocket it will allow me to send one more echo and then it closes on the server. I need to get what I presume is a while statement and have it listen for an input like "playermsg 'has started a game'" and have it actually run that function on the server.

Will I be able to get this to run, almost seems like it has to be in the background? I've been using [nc(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) for reference and some websites said to try `-d` and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. I did indeed need a while statement.

```
openSocket
while read -r value; do
    val=${value:10}
    if [[ "$value" == playermsg* ]]; then 
        val=${value:10}
        playermsg $val
    elif [[ "$value" == servermsg* ]]; then 
        val=${value:10}
        servermsg $val
    else
        echo "Returned "$value
        echo "Value was "$val
    fi
done
```

So now on the second computer I simply run

```
echo "playermsg testing" >/dev/tcp/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/4444
```

Then the server displays the following:

```
15:29:36 [SERVER] Starting the Game Listener
15:29:36 [SERVER] Opening Listener on port 4440
15:29:36 [SERVER] Now listening on port 4440
15:29:37 [PLAYER] testing
```